# Некорректно работает phpStorm с подсказками

Tags: php, phpstorm

Всем привет!

Работаю в phpStorm и проекте yii2. Сначала все шло хорошо. Затем после очередного открытия данного проекта, исчезли возможности подсказки IDE касательно классов и методов классов. Например, создаю модель Category, где прописываю:

```
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
```

В сообщениях phpStorm в нижней панели на вкладке Problems появляется сообщение 'Undefined class ActiveRecord'. Или, например, в контроллере прописываю use для модели Category, и IDE PHPStorm не видит такой путь. А, если писать в методе контроллера следующее:

```
 $this->data = Category::find()->all();
```

То при наборе текста, не подсвечивает методы Category, но видит свойство data у объекта $this. И таких примеров много. Как вернуть режим подсказок от phpStorm, чтобы правильно подсвечивало методы и свойства, а также namespace и use?

Comment: Решил проблему, перенеся в новую папку проект. После чего в phpStorm открыл его вновь и все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Иногда шторм глючит. Попробуйте в меню выбрать

`File` → `Invalidate Caches`

и перезагрузить шторм. Он пересчитает данные и индексы и должно стать хорошо.

Comment: Не помогло, но за совет спасибо.